# What is the proper way to establish API thread-safety for an API that has both suspend and non-suspend functions?

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, concurrency, thread-safety, kotlin-coroutines

Suppose I have the following thread-safe class (note there are no `suspend` functions):

```
@AnyThread
class MyClass {

    @AnyThread
    fun foo(): Int {
        runWithoutConcurrency()
        // .. the rest
    }

    @AnyThread
    fun bar(): Int {
        runWithoutConcurrency()
        // .. the rest
    }

    @Synchronized
    private fun runWithoutConcurrency() { /* .. */ }
}
```

Imagine there is a critical section (that is not thread-safe on its own). So it is put at  `runWithoutConcurrency()` and is marked as `@Synchronized`, thus the entire class is thread-safe.

Now let's change `foo()` to be a `suspend` function. How would I achieve the same thread-safety?

ADDED MORE DETAILS:

If API consisted solely from `suspend` functions, then I would use Kotlin coroutines `Mutex`. So the question here is how to "marry" Java synchronization (which is required anyway to make `bar()` thread-safe) with `Mutex` usage (which is required anyway to make `suspend foo()` thread-safe).

Comment: Do you mean `runWithoutConcurrency()` remains the same with its `@Synchronized` and we need to invoke it from a suspend function? Or do you ask what is an equivalent of `@Synchronized` in the coroutine world?

Comment: @broot, I added more details to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synchronized blocks in Java are waiting by blocking the thread, so we should generally try to avoid calling them from coroutines. If we don't have another option, then depending on the specific case we can use `Mutex`, `Dispatchers.IO` or a mix of them.

1.. If the synchronized method is invoked only in a single place or we control all such places and all of them are suspending - we can use `Mutex`:

```kotlin
mutex.withLock {
    runWithoutConcurrency()
}
```

I believe this should be safe, because if we guaranteed we never invoke `runWithoutConcurrency()` concurrently, then it will never block. Of course, we have to use exactly the same `mutex` object in all call sites.

2.. As suggested by @Tenfour04, if we invoke the method from both coroutine and non-coroutine contexts, but we still control all call sites (as in your example), we can choose to still use the solution based on mutex and for non-suspend contexts use `runBlocking()` to start a coroutine. The resulting code could look like this:

```kotlin
private val mutex = Mutex()

suspend fun foo(): Int {
    mutex.withLock {
        runWithoutConcurrency()
    }
}

fun bar(): Int {
    runBlocking {
        mutex.withLock {
            runWithoutConcurrency()
        }
    }
}
```

The idea here is to synchronize both cases using the same synchronization mechanism and depending on the case either suspend or block. Threads coming through `foo()` will never block, only suspend. Threads coming from `bar()` may block if `runWithoutConcurrency()` is in use, but this is the same as using the synchronized method itself.

3.. If we can't control all call sites of the synchronized method or we can't easily pass the mutex to all call sites, we can handle this case similarly to any other blocking code - by using `Dispatchers.IO`:

```kotlin
withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    runWithoutConcurrency()
}
```

`IO` in this case may sound counter-intuitive as we don't do any I/O here, but as a matter of fact, `Dispatchers.IO` could/should be used for any kind of blocking code, not only I/O. I still suggest putting this in a mutex if possible - this way we block at most a single IO thread instead of one thread per call.

Situation will be a little different if there are multiple `@Synchronized` methods as all of them are synchronized using the same object, but general rules still apply.

Comment: Could you use `runBlocking { mutex.withLock { runWithoutConcurrency() } }` for the `bar()` function? Then you are only blocking the calling thread like `synchronized` would do, without also blocking an IO dispatcher thread. `bar` can't use `withContext` without using `runBlocking` anyway.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Ohh, I like the idea! Thank you, I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you, option number 2 looks good to me.

Comment: @VitKhudenko This is actually a pretty interesting case, I never tried this myself. If you find any problems with this solution, please let me know in comments!